# How to Export and Import Dataverse Choices between Environments

Tags: power-automate, dataverse

We are trying to export a Managed Solution from a Power Automate Development Envronment to a seperate Production one. On Importing the Solution it complains of :

> "Import failed due to missing dependencies"

It then lists the missing dependencies and they are all Choice columns (Example):

> additionalOcSignerYN cr3b4_additionalocsigneryn Choice MVV (AdditionalOcSignerYN) Column

I can see in the exported solution zip it has not included the Choice column data (simple Yes\No).

I have then installed and attempted to use the Common Data Service Configuration Migration Tool to migrate the data the Solution relies on. I have Created a Schema from the Solution, Exported the Data and then attempted to import it. It also fails to import due to the missing Choice columns. In the Schema I note that the Field that references the Global Choice schema has been included but the Choice hasn't been included.

```
<entities >
  <entity name="cr3b4_mvv" displayname="MVV" etc="10121" primaryidfield="cr3b4_mvvid" primarynamefield="cr3b4_mvvname" disableplugins="false">
    <fields>
      <field displayname="AdditionalOcSignerYN" name="cr3b4_additionalocsigneryn" type="optionsetvalue" customfield="true" />
    </fields>
  </entity>
</entities>
```

I considered recreating the Global Choices manually in Production but also noted it would create new field prefixes i.e. "cr3b4_" would be something different and hence break the import.

How do I Export and Import a Solution that references Global Choices from one environment to another please?

Comment: I'd suggest raising that with Microsoft directly.  You may get an answer here but going direct to MS may be quicker.

Comment: To me it seems the `AdditionalOcSignerYN` column is not present on your target environment. Is that correct? If yes, it probably is part of a managed solution that needs to be installed before you attempt to import your solution.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen yes. We are attempting to import the solution into the target environment. It won't import without the global Choice column being defined prior to the import. I was hoping that exporting the solution would includee the global Choice column but it doesn't unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the "Add required components" button to add it to the solution?
Configuration migration tool, will not add schema updates to another environment only data.

When you want to add a choice column into a solution and import it into another solution you just need to add that column and the choice to your solution.

For example, I have created a solution "Solution 1" where I added the "Account" table, created a new Choice column "YN new choice" and created a new global choice options "YN new global choice"

[image: New choice column solution 1]

Then, I created "Solution 2" with a different publisher and added some customization to the Account main form where I use the column created in "Solution 1"

[image: Account main form solution 2]

If I try to export "Solution 2" and import it into a new environment, I'll get an error because the choice column was used in the form, but the column and choice were not added to the solution. As you have seen already just having the column  in the solution is not enough.

[image: Missing dependencies]

So, you have 2 options:

1. Manually add the missing components
2. Use the "Add required components" button

For option 1, you have to track and add each component manually. If it is the choice column and options, go to the table that contains  that column. If the table is not part of your solution you will have to add it (for example, if you have a view that references that column from a related table).

Navigate to "Columns"  and click on "Add subcomponentes"

[image: Account columns]
[image: add subcomponents]

Search for the choice column and add it to the solution
[image: add choice]

Next, we need to add the options. In your solution, select the "All" option and click on "Add existing"

[image: all objects]

Then go to "More" and click on "Choice"

[image: existing choice]

Search the choice and add it to the solution

[image: add choice options]

For option 2.

*Please be aware that this "Add required components" can sometimes add more components than the ones you might want (for example, components from another solution that you already imported in prod and wanted to keep separated)*

Select the component in your solution and then click on "Add required components", after some time, it will add the dependencies automatically.

[image: Add required components]
[image: added dependency]

You have added the dependency the form had, but now you need to add the dependency for the choice column, select it and click on "Add required components"

[image: column dependency]
Again, after some seconds you should see that the "Choice" component was automatically added.

[image: choice added]

Now, you can export you solution as managed again, and import in the other environment.

[image: Import success]

Please let me know if this helps.